# Namespaces and projects

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to introduce namespaces to a solution.

I have three projects in one solution:

```
Business Logic Layer
Data Access Layer
User Interface Layer
```

The namespaces of the classes in the business logic layer and data access layer are as follows:

```
companyname.applicationname.layername
```

If I want to access a class in the Data Logic Layer then I have to include the following statement:

```
Imports DataAccessLayer.companyname.applicationname.layername
```

I don't want to have DataAccessLayer as the first node.  Is there a way around this or am I misunderstanding something fundamental about namespaces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Namespace Naming Guidelines Check this:

[Namespace Naming Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/893ke618%28VS.71%29.aspx)

Try setting: Assembly Name & Default Namespace

[image]

Comment: Thanks +1.  This is what I was looking for.  Is it advisable to add Namespaces to the UI layer?, which is a Windows Forms.  Windows Forms are already part of a Namespace.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure of exactly what you're after, but here's a few options:

Import DataAccessLayer, then referring to the sub-namespaces directly:

```
Imports DataAccessLayer
...
companyname.applicationname.layername.mymethod(abc)
```

Make your assembly namespace in the project properties "DataAccessLayer".  Then you won't need to import DataAccessLayer, just import companyname... or refer to companyname... directly.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to define that class inside the desired namespace like,

```
Namespace companyname.applicationname
  Public Class layername

  End  Class
End Namespace
```

Or can make default namespace by changing property,
 [image]